# how to get values from two child tables for parent table

Tags: mysql

i have three tables (invoice,rate,rate_slap)
i have weight and no_of_package in invoice table
if invoice.weight < = rate.weight then it will return that table rate.weight
else weight < = rate_slap.weight then it will return that table rate_slap.weight

but return any one of the table values not from both.

```
SELECT 
rate.`minimum_wgt`, 
slap.`slap_weight`
FROM m_ac_customer_rate rate
LEFT JOIN m_ac_customer_rate_slap slap ON (rate.minimum_wgt<=15) 
OR (slap.slap_weight<=15)
WHERE rate.customer_rate_id=slap.customer_rate_master 
AND `customer_name`=1007
AND `destination_name`=3
AND `service_type`=1
AND `shipment_type`='D'
AND `payment_mode`='CASH';
```

sample data

invoice table

```
invoice_no,weight,total_carton
 2142423,   10.4,     5
```

rate table

```
invoice_no,weight,rate_per_kg
2142423 , 15.8,      150.00
```

rate_slap table

```
rateslap_id,weight,rate_per_kg
2142423 , 10.8,      10.00
```

Comment: Great.  Is there an actual question here?  Can you add sample data for both tables?

Comment: i have add data and column above

Comment: @MahendranB, could you please add your expected output in table format?

Answer (score 0):

This will select both weights (if existing) in a subquery together with the invoice weight and then do a CASE... in the main query to select the correct one

```
SELECT no_of_package, 
  CASE WHEN weight <= rate_weight THEN rate_weight
       WHEN weight <= slap_weight THEN slap_weight
       ELSE 0
       END AS other_weight
FROM 
  (SELECT i.weight, IFNULL(r.weight, 0) as rate_weight, IFNULL(rs.weight, 0) as slap_weight
   FROM invoice I
   LEFT JOIN rate r ON r.invoice_no = i.invoice_no AND minimum_wgt <= 15
   LEFT JOIN rate_slap rs ON rs.invoice_no = i.invoice_no AND slap_weight <= 15
   WHERE customer_name = 1007
     AND destination_name = 3
     AND service_type = 1
     AND shipment_type = 'D'
     AND payment_mode = 'CASH')
```

I chose 0 as default for the CASE, maybe it should be the weight from invoice instead. You need to adjust the table names, I used the short version of the names